# How to display result of query in bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, sql, modal-dialog

Good afternoon colleagues, I am in a web design course, this work was presented to me, which is a search page, which should show the user's information in a MODAL, obtaining it from the database.

I managed to make the Modal work, but, it throws all the information of the table, when I try to do the query, it does not show me anything.

I hope you can guide me with this detail

```
    <?php

//Conexion para el Modal
$con =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","");
$db = mysqli_select_db($con, 'requi');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">Search panel</a>
</nav>
<meta charset="UTF=8">
<hr weight= "100%">
<title>Buscar requisicion</titLe>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <h2>Buscar requisición</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <form class="form-outline">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Ingresa el ID" name ="id" aria-label="Search">
    <!--<button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" name="search">Buscar</button>-->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="smodal">Busqueda</button>     
 </div>

 <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Mail Search</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Your data: </p> 
       </div>
       <div>
       <table style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <tr>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $query = "select * from info WHERE id = '$id'";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     $id = $row['id'];
     $correo = $row['correo'];
     $nombre = $row['nombre'];

     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$correo."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$nombre."</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
   }
}
   ?>
   </table>
       </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is `$_POST['search']` ever defined?

Comment: I use the name="smodal" but, I change to "search". Is correct?

Comment: ...no.  Smodal will open the modal but search query is triggered by the submitting the `$_POST['search']` - so do you ever submit this?  It looks like you don't.  The modal is created when the page loads so it only has the content there that it loads with - unless `$_POST['search']` exists there isn't anything to call.  If you wanted this to happen 'on the fly' you'd need to use ajax